# PATH .bash_profile, Home Brew, rvm, and one line I can't shake upon opening up a shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

1. OSX - 10.8.5
2. Running Homebrew
3. rvm

Whenever I open a new shell I get the following and I think, "ugh", thats not good.

```
Last login: Thu Nov  7 07:12:43 on ttys000
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I then run `echo $PATH` and get

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Matthew$ echo $PATH
/Users/Matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/Matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/Matthew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/Matthew/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Matthew$
```

I think my .bash_profile is a mess and I really would appreciate some ninja guidance...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Terminal, you begin a bash shell session. You can set some commands to run every time you start a bash session. The place to put these initial bash commands is usually in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. See if you have any reference to the file `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`there and check if that file actually exists on your machine.

UPDATE:

I have heard of problems if o installed rvm as sudo. Try removing it and reinstalling again without sudo:

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh \ 
 /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm
sudo /usr/sbin/groupdel rvm # this might fail, it's not that important
```

Reopen terminal and make sure rvm ins removed:

```
env | grep rvm
```

It should return empty if not try to restart de computer. After it return empty you can install it:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Comment: tiagotex, I just ran `$ open /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and the file doesn't exist.  I also checked both the .bashrc and .bash_profile and I couldn't find any reference to that file.

Comment: I ran the sudo commands and it seems to have not worked, because when I run `env | grep rvm` I get,
`PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
Additionally, when I open a new terminal it still comes up. with `-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory`